# MySQL TRIGGER update table

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Нужно тригером обновлять ту же таблицу, точнее одно ее поле и вписать туда количество заполненых полей - в строку где IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = 35 нужно вписать количество других строк для данного IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, в данном примере VALUE дожно быть 5, а не 10.

вот пример выборки для одного элемента 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`CREATE TRIGGER update_property BEFORE INSERT 
ON b_iblock_element_property FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = 35 
THEN
   SET
      NEW.value = count 
END
IF`

Не могу написать запрос, спасибо всем кто подскажет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки сделал тригер:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_property |
CREATE TRIGGER update_property BEFORE UPDATE ON b_iblock_element_property
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '35' THEN
SET NEW.VALUE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b_iblock_element_property WHERE
IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID = NEW.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID);
END IF;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```